# I can't set the Internet permission in my Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to test a Xamarin Android application that consumes a WCF service. I know that I have to go to project properties and set "Internet" as a needed permission, but I don't see the list of permissions that I could select. I get this:

[image: Screenshot of window]

I know that I should see a list of permissions that I can check or uncheck according to the application's needs.

I am using VS2019 community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file AnroidManifest.xml manually.

Comment: I have serach the android.manifest file and it is in the debug folder, so I guess it would be replace every time I will compile. Am I wrong?

Comment: Wrong name I've changed it above, check again.

Comment: In the properties folder?